# Display product categories + child-categories on a single product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I currently use that code to display product category on woocommerce single-product pages :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'add_cat_single_title', 6 );
function add_cat_single_title() {
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'product_cat');
    if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms)) { ?>
        <div class="cat-term-title-single" style="display: block;">Cat : <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_term_link($terms[0])); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($terms[0]->name); ?></a></div>
    <?php }
}
```

That code displays only 1 category. If the product is from several categories or child categories, they are not displayed.

Some help to display every terms would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found in woocommerce meta.php template :

```
<?php echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
```